# Browsing online folder structure - handling back button (save previous view?)

Tags: android

So I have created an app to browse online files and folders, it uses an API in order to list the files and folders and display them.

I am using a custom ListView to display the files and folders.

The user can click on a folder, and it will then refresh the same Activity ListView and display the files and folders within that folder.

Now, I am handling the `BACK` button to pull in the files and folders from the parent directory.  But it can be quite slow to load the files and folders (a few seconds).  I think it would be better if it is more instantaneous to go back to the previous folder directory.

Is there anyway to somehow save the previous View or Activity somehow?  And then just show it again, without having to reload all the folders again when the back button is pressed?

Apologies if this is a silly question but I am a novice!

Here is my back button code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    //if they hit back button
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //they have pressed the back key so go up a folder 
        if((currentPath != ROOT)){

            currentPath = currentPath.getParent(); //get Parent folder

            //reload the files and folders here!

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(currentPath == DbxPath.ROOT)
            {
                //at root level so go back to main activity
                Intent intentMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intentMain);
                return true;
            }

        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `ArrayList<Adapter>` that would store the current adapter, if the user enters a directory, and pop one, and use it, if the user wants to go up one directory. That way you don't even have to build the `Adapter` you use with your `ListView` when back is pressed, just set it.

Alternative way might be even better, if you create a `HashMap<Sting, Adapter>`, where the key is the path to the folder, and `Adapter` is the populated `Adapter`, and it would work like a cache, that you can use. When you have to load a folder, you check if the `HashMap` has an entry with the path as key, and use that `Adapter`, if there is, otherwise you request from the network, and you put the populated `Adapter` in the `HashMap`.

I would recommend this approach, but that would mean you don't load folders twice, even if you enter a folder. That might be what you want, but not in every cases.

Also, have a look at `onBackPressed ()` of the Activity class, that makes easier handling the back key.

Comment: sounds interesting!  I like these ideas.  I might try the first out as it seems simpler. Although I guess I would need to track the number of adapters in the Array.  So if they navigate down 5 folders, there would be 4 adaapters in the Array, if they hit back, I would need the previous one...

Comment: Actually I missed you point about popping the last one when they move back.  Make sense.  Don't need to track anything,

Comment: OK it works when you hit the back button.  But if a user clicks another folder, its crashes as my arrayList of paths is different (i.e it still thinks its the previous one).  Because when the user clicks on a listItem, I get the path of the clicked item like this:  DbxPath path = paths.get(position);  But it seems when you go back to the previous adapter, the paths ArrayList will not have moved back obviously.  Do I need to store that in an ArrayList also?

Comment: I did the same thing for the paths array.   ArrayList<ArrayList<Paths>> historyPathsList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Paths>>();  So I'm storing the paths ArrayList inside an ArrayList. So I can go back to the previous one when they hit back.  I might try using the HashMap, would it use a lot of memory though if you are adding to it all the time when the user browses..

Comment: I believe the `Map` approach is the best one.  However I would rather store the list that drives the adapter - and keep only one adapter, calling `notifyDataSetChanged` when replacing the list.

Comment: if I were to use the HashMap - can you use an ArrayList as a key? Like this:                                                                                            HashMap<ArrayList<Path>, ImageAdapter> historyMap = new HashMap<ArrayList<Path>, ImageAdapter>();                                                        How would I retrieve the previous path and adapter?  How would you search the adapter?

Comment: Why would you want to use a List as the key? The previous path should be found out from the current path, I guess. You chop off one part of the current, like `/thing/directory` becomes `/thing`. After you got the path, you can use get with the new path as key, and you get the Adapter. I gave you the simpliest solution possible, but Aleks G is right, it is better to cache the List only, and have only one Adapter instance.